# matplotlib: display xticklabels 'groups'

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to show a group of xlabels are in the same group? Like the 'Group A' and 'Group B' labels as shown in the figure below.

[image]

The closest solution I can find is additional xaxis on top (twiny), but I would prefer it at the bottom with existing xticklabels.

Comment: It looks like a duplicate. Thanks BrenBarn!